# Sharing variables across ASP.NET Core controllers and first initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a set of variables that should be accessable from the various controllers. Because it's quite a lengthy operation to load them in I would like to only load them in once at the startup of the application and afterwards be able to access them across the various controllers setup.

Right now my best solution was using a static object that intializes and holds all the variables by calling a method "Initialize", but it feels quite hacked in and improper.

What would be a better solution to achieve the same?

Comment: Can it remain as a static class? I'd opt for that over registering a type as a singleton in a container, because the intent is not clear enough that it must be a singleton instance to work correctly, whereas with a static class and static properties your intent is clear.

Comment: It could remain a static class. Looking at the implementation of the singleton I think the intent with the static class is probably clearer for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create instance class, put all your properties in it and register it as a Singleton in DI container. You will receive that instance for each controller in constructor.
In Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSingleton<YourPropertiesClass()>;
```

Another option would be to user InMemoryCache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory
But for your situation I think that is overcomplication.